# stack overflow in F# compiler running under mono

Tags: f#, mono, stack-overflow, llvm-fs

I'm updating the tooling for my project [llvm-fs](https://github.com/fsprojects/llvm-fs), so I installed the new version of mono and tried to compile it. Using either `mono 3.10.0` with `fsharpc 3.1` under OS X or `mono 3.2.8` with `fsharpc 3.0` under ubuntu the compile fails with a stack overflow:

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.StackOverflowException: The requested operation caused a stack overflow.
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) object:__icall_wrapper_mono_object_isinst (object,intptr)
  at (wrapper castclass) object:__castclass_with_cache (object,intptr,intptr)
  at Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.Driver+DelayedDisposables.System-IDisposable-Dispose () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.Driver.typecheckAndCompile (System.String[] argv, Boolean bannerAlreadyPrinted, Exiter exiter, Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.ErrorLoggerProvider errorLoggerProvider) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.Driver.mainCompile (System.String[] argv, Boolean bannerAlreadyPrinted, Exiter exiter) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.CommandLineMain.runMain (System.String[] argv) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.CommandLineMain.main (System.String[] argv) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.StackOverflowException: The requested operation caused a stack overflow.
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) object:__icall_wrapper_mono_object_isinst (object,intptr)
  at (wrapper castclass) object:__castclass_with_cache (object,intptr,intptr)
  at Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.Driver+DelayedDisposables.System-IDisposable-Dispose () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.Driver.typecheckAndCompile (System.String[] argv, Boolean bannerAlreadyPrinted, Exiter exiter, Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.ErrorLoggerProvider errorLoggerProvider) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.Driver.mainCompile (System.String[] argv, Boolean bannerAlreadyPrinted, Exiter exiter) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.CommandLineMain.runMain (System.String[] argv) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.CommandLineMain.main (System.String[] argv) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

You can reproduce this error on linux or OS X by doing the following:

```
git clone git@github.com:fsprojects/llvm-fs.git
cd llvm-fs/
FSC=fsharpc ./build.bash
```

Under windows `fsc 12.0.30815.0` the compile completes with no errors:

```
fsc --nologo --debug --sig:LLVMFSharp.fsi --target:library --out:LLVMFSharp.dll src/LLVM/FFIUtil.fs src/LLVM/Generated.fs src/LLVM/Core.fs src/LLVM/BitReader.fs src/LLVM/ExecutionEngine.fs src/LLVM/Extra.fs src/LLVM/Target.fs src/LLVM/Quote.fs
```

Is this a known issue and is there any way to work around it? I've tried passing different options to the mono runtime and none resulted in the compiler exiting normally. I do remember in the past mono has had some problems respecting tailcall instructions but I thought that those problems were mostly resolved. Thanks!

Comment: I forgot to say that this compile worked fine with the old mono which came with an F# 2.0 compiler (I'm not sure of the exact versions though).

Comment: This looks like a regression in the compiler.  I would report it as a bug.

Comment: in case anyone is following this here is the bug report https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=24752

Comment: It is probably a good idea to file this as an F# compiler bug as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is too long for a comment, but the error is triggered by this bit of code from generated.fs (in that commenting it out stops the stack overflow - there is an error later once this is commented out) (from line 6496-6506):

```
 [<DllImport(
            llvmAssemblyName,
            EntryPoint="LLVMRunFunction",
            CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl,
            CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)>]
        extern void* (* LLVMGenericValueRef *) runFunctionNative(
            void* (* LLVMExecutionEngineRef *) EE,
            void* (* LLVMValueRef *) F,
            uint32 NumArgs,
            void* (* LLVMGenericValueRef* *) Args)
        // I don't know how to generate an "F# friendly" version of LLVMRunFunction
```

The crash is occuring in the code that outputs the signature file.

Disabling the signature file fixes the problem (but there is still an underlying bug somewhere).

Comment: Thank you for the pointers and the work around. Turning off signature file generation is a fine workaround for me especially since I can just use the signature output from the windows build. I'll add a bug report to mono as you suggest when I get a bit of time.